# Vectorized sum and product with list of pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of Data Frames, each corresponding to a different time period t from 0 to N. Each data frame has multiple types, I need to preform the calculation below for each type in the data frame.

An example data set would be as follows, I made each `df` in the list the same values for simplicity but the calculation would remain the same.

```
d = {'type': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y':[3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

l = []
window = 20
[l.append(df.copy(deep=True)) for i in range(window)]
```

I need to compute a vectored sum `$$\sum$$` and product `$$\prod$$` using the above list of dataframes for each type (a, b, c) in an efficient manner. e.g. for each calculation below I need to filter by a single type `df[df['type'] == 'a']` for every `df` in the list.

[image]

If I use a `df.groupby('type')` on every `df` in the list it could be very slow using a larger data set. The same goes if I use nested for loops for the sum and the product and filtering by type in each iteration of the for loop. How can I compute this sum product in an efficient manner ?

*Update*

One possible way as suggested in the comments is below, however this will start to be very inefficient if I use a larger dataset or window:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

d = {'type': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y':[3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

l = []
window = 20
for i in range(window):
    df['window'] = i
    l.append(df.copy(deep=True))
df = pd.concat(l)

sums = {}
types = df['type'].unique()
for s in types:
    sums[s] = 0
    tdf = df[df['type'] == s]
    for i in range(window):
        sums[s] += tdf[tdf['window'] == i]['x'].values[0] * math.prod(2 - tdf[tdf['window'] == i+1]['x'].values[0] for i in range(0, window-1)) * tdf[tdf['window'] == i]['y'].values[0]
```

Comment: Do you mean `pd.concat`enated dataframe ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah I could do `pd.concat(l)` on the list and add the int of the window to each frame there. I'm still not sure how I can make that run efficiently as well

Comment: What does “preform the finally” mean?  Typo maybe,

Comment: @Bill good catch fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your intent correctly, you could try something along these lines.

```
sums = {}
x_col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('x')
for s, tdf in df.groupby('type'):
    sums[s] = np.dot(tdf['x'], tdf['y']) * np.prod(2 - tdf['x'].iloc[1:])
```

This gets the same results on your example and a few other examples I tried as the reference code, and is much faster. It also mostly stays within Pandas.

---

**EDIT**: If you're willing to do the whole computation in Numpy, you can get a 3x speedup. (More, if you have a large number of groups.) However, this comes at the cost of the code being much harder to read.

```
def run():
    # Convert to numpy
    type_ = df['type'].values
    x = df['x'].values
    y = df['y'].values
    uniques, codes = np.unique(type_, return_inverse=True)

    # Set up intermediate arrays
    dot_prod = np.zeros(len(uniques))
    per_type_prod = np.ones(len(uniques) + 1)

    # Compute dot product of x and y within each group
    prod = x * y
    np.add.at(dot_prod, codes, prod)

    # Compute (2 - x).prod() within each group, dropping first sample
    per_type_prod_before_multiply = 2 - x
    # Drop first instance of each type
    for i in range(len(uniques)):
        codes[(codes == i).argmax()] = -1

    np.multiply.at(per_type_prod, codes, per_type_prod_before_multiply)
    # Last element is garbage, result of multiplying thrown away first element.
    per_type_prod = per_type_prod[:-1]
    # Convert to dictionary
    sums = {k: v for k, v in zip(uniques, per_type_prod * dot_prod)}
    return sums
```

This avoids `df.groupby()` by having an array for each of the N groups, and choosing which element to add into by the `codes` array.